# How to use RedirectToAction to redirect to the default action of different controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to do a RedirectToAction from http://mywebsite/Home/ using the following code:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Profile", new { id = formValues["id"] });
```

The above code will succesfully take me to

http://mywebsite/Profile/Index/223224

What do I have to do to make it redirect to

http://mywebsite/Profile/223224

Thank you.

I figured out how to do this.

First I have to add custom route rule:

```
routes.MapRoute("Profile", "Profile/{id}", new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Then I can do the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public RedirectResult Index(FormCollection formValues)
{
   return Redirect("~/Survey/" + formValues["Id"]);
}
```

Comment: can you show us your route definitions?

Comment: I never manually defined one so I assume I am using the default route definition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do:

```
return RedirectToAction("","Profile", new { id = formValues["id"] });
```

Comment: For this very reason, I've actually had better luck changing the default route definition to /{controller}/{id}/{action}. You will probably need a second route of /{controller}/{action} and some guards to help determine which is correct. Routing ain't easy in all but the simplest of cases :-)

Comment: Yup, its never easy unless its the simplest of cases.  I'm learning this the hard way! :)  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon exact same problem. Got it solved by redirecting using **route name**:

```
return RedirectToRoute("profile", new { action = "" });
```

all variables will be remembered so if you have Url like /{x}/{y}/Profile/{action}/{id} you just need to clear action as I did.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your / controller is named "Home"

```
Return RedirectToRoute(new {controller="Home",action="Index",id=formValues["id"]});
```

Hmm I suppose this would be still /Index/num though... I'm not sure if you can get away with leaving out the Index bit there without custom routing.